# Changing the background of a picture in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a logo in which the whole background is in white. I want to remove the backgroun while showing on MATLAB. 
The original picture is called gmd.png .

I turn every completely white pixel of it to black. Then, I save this new array to a new picture. When I open the new picture outside MATLAB, it looks as expected; all the white pixels are now black but when I try to show it up in MATLAB with a low-level function,a white picture shows up. I don't know where the problem is. Here is the piece of code that I've written:

```
gmd=imread('gmd.png');
[nx ny nz]=size(gmd);
for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
        if gmd(i,j,1)==255 && gmd(i,j,2)==255 && gmd(i,j,3)==255
            gmd(i,j,:)=0;
        end
    end
end
imwrite(gmd,'gmdlogosaf.png');
[gmdlogosaf,map,gmdlogoalpha]=imread('gmdlogosaf.png');
image(gmdlogosaf,'AlphaData',gmdlogoalpha);
```

The logo is attached to this message.
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `imshow(gmdlogosaf)` instead

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thank you; I don't know how I didn't think of it!